# Стриминг через cvlc на удалённом сервере через ssh выдаёт ошибку

Tags: streaming, vlc, x11, rtsp

Я пытаюсь организовать стриминг видеофайла с удалённого сервера. Подключаюсь к нему по ssh и затем пишу команду:

```
cvlc video.mp4 --sout '#rtp{dst=localhost,port=554,sdp=rtsp://hse.auditory.ru:8083/test.sdp}'
```

В результате, я получаю следующие строки:

`ubuntu@petrov:~$ cvlc video.mp4 --sout '#rtp{dst=localhost,port=554,sdp=rtsp://hse.auditory.ru:8083/test.sdp}'
VLC media player 2.2.2 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.2-0-g6259d80)
[0000000001421768] core interface error: no suitable interface module
[000000000130e148] core libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[0000000001421768] dbus interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus session daemon: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
[0000000001421768] core interface error: no suitable interface module
[000000000130e148] core libvlc error: interface "dbus,none" initialization failed
[0000000001421768] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[00007ff3ec000fd8] stream_out_rtp stream out: Consider passing --rtsp-host=IP on the command line instead.
[00007ff3ec000fd8] core stream out error: socket bind error: Permission denied
[00007ff3ec000fd8] core stream out error: cannot create socket(s) for HTTP host
[00007ff3ec000fd8] stream_out_rtp stream out error: cannot export SDP as RTSP`

`socket bind error: Permission denied` - это я ещё понимаю: порты, наверное, надо открыть. А вот что с иксами не так? cvlv - это же консольная программа. Она по-умолчанию не должна пользоваться иксами...

UPD: Мне принципиально стримить через rtsp

Comment: Порты ниже 1024 должны биндиться от рута.

Answer (score -1):

Вот такое решение нашёл:

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -d -m cvlc $1 -Idummy :sout="#transcode{vcodec=mp2v,vb=800,scale=1,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:std{access=udp,mux=ts,dst=239.0.0.92:8208}" :no-sout-rtp-sap :no-sout-standard-sap :sout-keepsud vlc://quit
```

[Ссылка](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=84070) на тред.

Comment: Та же самая ошибка возникает. И мне принципиально стримить через rtsp.